# Sample rows of a list of matrices based on numbers from another list

Tags: r, list, matrix, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a list of matrices from which I want to randomly draw rows based on the numbers of another list. Here is the list of matrices:

```
x <- list(`1` = matrix(1:20, nrow=10), `2` = matrix(1:20, nrow=10))
```

Here is the list of numbers

```
y <- list(`1` = 2, `2` = 3) #for `1` I want to draw 2 rows and for `2` I want to draw 3 rows
```

The final list will look like this:

```
$`1`
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   11
 [2,]    6   16

$`1`
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   11
 [2,]    7   17 
 [3,]    9   19
```

How to achieve this in base R? Thanks for any help!

Comment: will the two lists be of the same length? or we can have `y<-list(\`2\` =3)` without the first element?

Comment: Hi @Onyambu, the two lists have different length. That's why I have a separate list that stores the lengths for drawing rows in `x`

Comment: Technically your two lists have the same lengths. The answer accepted assumes the two losts have the same lengths with the same ordering.

Comment: Oh, I understood you. You mean the list of matrices and the list of number drawn? Yes, they do have the same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` in `base R` - loop over the corresponding `list` elements of 'x' and 'y' sample the rows of `matrix`es in 'x' based on the values in 'y'

```
Map(function(u, v) u[sample(seq_len(nrow(u)), v),], x, y)
$`1`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   19
[2,]    6   16

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   13
[2,]    8   18
[3,]    5   15
```

---

Or use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(x, y,  ~ .x[sample(seq_len(nrow(.x)), .y), ])
```

If we convert to `tibble`, then `slice_sample` can be used as well

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
map2(x, y,  ~ .x %>% 
   as.data.frame %>%
   as_tibble %>% 
   slice_sample(n = .y))
$`1`
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     V1    V2
  <int> <int>
1     4    14
2     7    17

$`2`
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     V1    V2
  <int> <int>
1     8    18
2     6    16
3     9    19
```